# The class net.Stream is not discussed in Node.js' documentation but is being used for node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/lib/connection.js

```
var net = require('net');
var Connection = function(config) {
  ...
  config = config || {};
  this.stream = config.stream || new net.Stream();
  ...
}
```

There is no mention at all of net.Stream in the documentation.
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just an alias to `Socket`.

```
exports.Stream = Socket; // Legacy naming.
```

Source: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L295